# Running Jobs in Kubernetes

Tags: selenium, kubernetes

I'm trying to develop a scraping app in which I run a lot of different selenium scripts that are all dependent upon each other. I figured that using Kubernetes would be a good idea for this. In order for this to work, I need the scripts to be able to communicate with each other so I can trigger them to run after each other. How can I accomplish this?

---

This is an example of some logic that I'm want to perform:

1. Fire of an container, X, that eventually creates a JSON file of some gathered data
2. Give access to the JSON file to another container, Y.
3. Trigger the Y container to run

---

I would appreciate any help that I can get!

Comment: Have you tried airflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) sounds exactly like the stuff you'd like to achieve.

> A Job creates one or more Pods and ensures that a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful completions. When a specified number of successful completions is reached, the task (ie, Job) is complete. Deleting a Job will clean up the Pods it created.
>
> A simple case is to create one Job object in order to reliably run one Pod to completion. The Job object will start a new Pod if the first Pod fails or is deleted (for example due to a node hardware failure or a node reboot).
>
> You can also use a Job to run multiple Pods in parallel.

Additionally, you might be interested in a concept of [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

> Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:
>
> Init containers always run to completion.
>      Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts..
>
> If a Pod’s init container fails, Kubernetes repeatedly restarts the Pod until the init container succeeds.

And PV+PVC to store and share the data (JSON,etc)

Comment: How could the jobs communicate with each other though, i.e. how would the first job trigger the next one? I believe k8s does not offer support for such workflows, and that's why tools like [Argo Workflow](https://github.com/argoproj/argo) have emerged.

Comment: @GeorgeTseres , i haven't heard about triggering Jobs by Job. Official doc says that job can start a controller Pod which can run some scripts . https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#single-job-starts-controller-pod